# Перезагрузка страницы при закрытии модального окна

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня следующая проблема на сайте. Есть кнопка "Оформить заказ", всплывает только тогда, когда там есть товар. Так вот, если я нажимаю оформить заказ, то в модальном окне подгружается iframe с оформлением. Но если я там удаляю все товары и закрываю модальное окно, кнопка "Оформить заказ" все еще висит, хотя по факту там уже нет товаров. Если перегрузить, то она пропадает. Как сделать такое принудительное обновление или сброс состояния? )))

Как я понимаю, можно использовать `location.reload();`, но все как-то медленно работает. Как можно ускорить все это действо? Чтобы на глаз как будто без перегрузки все работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навесьте кнопке класс, например, `.sending-button`.
В нужном месте, например, после выполнения функции закрытия модального окна, выполните следующее:

```
$('.sending-button').hide();
```

Чтобы ее отобразить, используйте

```
$('.sending-button').show();
```